# SFTPC error "Unexpected command parameter: -cmdfile" when calling from PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, cmd, sftp

I'm having a little trouble with my PowerShell script. I'm written this to upload `.txt` files to a SFTP to a folder on the root of the SFTP called `IN`.

I'm getting a SFTPC error. I'm guessing it's having trouble with my

```
$argu="$user -pw=$pw -cmdfile=$local\sftp.txt"
```

It's also moving my folder from `$Local` to `$destination`, which I'm guessing is become SFTPC is not working correctly?

I'm fairly new to PowerShell and I'm hopelessly lost.

Here's the error below.

```
ERROR: Unexpected command parameter: -cmdfile=C:\Users\bendonac\Script.

USAGE:
sftpc [username@]host[:port] OR -profile=file [-host=host] [-port=port] [-  
obfs=y|n] [-obfsKw=keyword] [-spn=SPN] [-sspi=y|n] [-sspiDlg=y|n]
```

And the script:

```
#PowerShell script to transfer files
#Set file list to null
$file_list=@()
$sftp_put=@()
#Set SFTP user and hostname
$user="username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"
#Set SFTP Password 
$pw='Secure Password'
#Set SFTP executable name
$sftp_prog="sftpc.exe " 
#Set local folder
$local="C:\Users\ben\Script test"
#Set SFTP Arguments
$argu="$user -pw=$pw -cmdfile=$local\sftp.txt"
#Build SFTP command line
$final=$sftp_prog+$argu
#Set target location 
$destination="UNC PATH"  

$files=get-childitem -filter *.txt $destination
foreach ($object1 in $files) {
$file_list+="put "+$object1.fullname + "\in" 
}
$file_list | out-file $local\sftp.txt


#*********Stage 2 upload to SFTP Server *********
set-location "C:\Program Files\Bitvise Tunnelier"
$sftp="sftpc.exe " 
$path="sftp_get_manifest.txt"
$argu="$user -pw=$pw -cmdfile=$local\sftp.txt" 
#$final= $sftp+$argu
cmd /c $final
try{
move-item -path $local -destination $destination -force
}
Catch {
$thereisanerror = ‘true’
}
#Remove old sftp script if it exists
if (test-path $local\sftp.txt) {remove-item $local\sftp.txt -force}
#Check last exit code for any SFTP errors

Error" -body "The SFTP download script has failed with an $lastexitcode        
error.     please investigate." -from "Ben@domain.com" -smtpserver    
"cas.domain.internal"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path to the script file contains spaces. So you have to wrap it to quotes to make it clear, where the path starts and ends.

```
$argu="$user -pw=$pw -cmdfile=`"$local\sftp.txt`""
```